# How to save editable table data to JSON which was used to draw the table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

First of all I just want to THANK YOU for looking at my post. I really appreciate it. Here's my problem -->

Say for example I have JSON document, which looks like this -->

{"superhero":[{"hero":"Magneto","name":"Max Eisenhardt","appearances_count":42},{"hero":"Superman","name":"Clark Kent","appearances_count":42}]}

I draw a table using this JSON document in html5 and JQuery. Now I would like to edit the  element of table which I drew using the JSON document and save the edited data in that JSON document.

My HTML is something like this -->

```
 <table>
    <thead>
        <th>Hero</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>AppearanceCount</th>    
    </thead>
    <tbody class="data"></tbody>
 </table>
```

And JQuery which I'm using to draw the table is something like this -->

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON("data.json", function(){
    var hero = this['hero'];
    var name = this['name'];
    var numCount = this['appearances_count'];

    var tbodyData = "<tr><td>"+hero+"</td><td>"+name+"</td><td>"+numCount+"</td></tr>"

    $(".data").append(tbodyData);
    });
});
```

data.json holding the json above. Please any help would be much appreciated. Thank you again for looking at my post.

Comment: You mean once you've created the table from the JSON document you want another jQuery function to edit the data in both the html and json further?

Answer (score 1):

The answer on how to do this manually will be too long, but the short story is that you should use a library that supports two way binding such as Knockout or Angular

Answer (score 1):

As Born2Code said, best to use a two way binding library. However, passing the table row, field name and new value to the following function would enable you to update the table and the object corresponding to the JSON document together.

```
function editTable(row, fieldName, newVal) {
  var column = '';
  // Get column number of target cell from table header
  var fieldElems = document.getElementsByTagName('th');
  for(var i = 0; i < fieldElems.length; i++) {
    if(fieldElems[i].innerHTML == fieldName) {
      column = i + 1;
      break;
    }
  }
  // Update target cell with new value
  document.getElementsByClassName('data')[0].children[row - 1].children[column - 1].innerHTML = newVal;
  // Update JSON document with new value
  data.superhero[row - 1][fieldName] = newVal;
}
```

For this to work you would need to ensure your json field names (e.g. 'hero') exactly match the table headers. Or you could alter the function to pass the column number directly instead of the fieldName. Also I'm treating the JSON document as a standard JS object - assuming you've parsed it and can then re-jsonify it when you need to send it back.

So to alter the 'Name' field of your second table row (Clark Kent), together with the JSON document, you would run:

```
editTable(2, 'Name', 'Spiderman')
```